# Feeding RNNs output back into its input

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say, I want to generate a sequence `a_n` out of a single vector `q` using a pre-trained RNN (e.g. `GRUCell`); the way I want to do this is like this:

```
q[0] := q
q[n+1] := GRU(q[n])
```

Basically using its own output on one step as its input during the next step. The problem is --- GRUCell requires specifying the whole input sequence at once, which I obviously can't do. I could try and do it like this:

```
for i in range(100):
    GRU.state = GRU.zero_state()
    q[i+1] := GRU(q[:i])[i]
# (obviously a bad pseudocode)
```

But that does not seem elegant, is not optimized and I can't figure out how to apply truncated backprop (feed just a part of the whole generated sequence at once...?).

So is there a better way to do this, or should I just stick to this ugly approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gist I made:

https://gist.github.com/CharlieCodex/f494b27698157ec9a802bc231d8dcf31

Make a lambda that applies the transformation from output space to input space.

Feel free to ask any questions!

Source:

```py
import tensorflow as tf


def self_feeding_rnn(cell, seqlen, Hin, Xin, processing=tf.identity):
    '''Unroll cell by feeding output (hidden_state) of cell back into in as input.
       Outputs are passed through `processing`. It is up to the caller to ensure that the processed
       outputs have suitable shape to be input.'''
    veclen = tf.shape(Xin)[-1]
    # this will grow from [ BATCHSIZE, 0, VELCEN ] to [ BATCHSIZE, SEQLEN, VECLEN ]
    buffer = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=seqlen)
    initial_state = (0, Hin, Xin, buffer)
    condition = lambda i, *_: i < seqlen
    print(initial_state)
    def do_time_step(i, state, xo, ta):
        Yt, Ht = cell(xo, state)
        Yro = processing(Yt)
        return (1+i, Ht, Yro, ta.write(i, Yro))

    _, Hout, _, final_ta = tf.while_loop(condition, do_time_step, initial_state)

    ta_stack = final_ta.stack()
    Yo = tf.reshape(ta_stack,shape=((-1, seqlen, veclen)))
    return Yo, Hout
```